# Dropbox interrupts VPN Connections

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, dropbox

Since today I experience a strange problem. I use several VPN Connections at home.

1. Hardware Device (Sophos Red 10) which establishes a VPN for my company telephone
2. Cisco VPN Client to connect to a company network

Today I recognized, that when I start Dropbox, the Red 10 looses the connection and is not able to reconnect until I stop Dropbox on my PC. First I thought, the reason may be that the Red 10 and my PC are connected to a TP-Link Acces Point in client mode and that there might be a port-conflict or something.

But then I recognized, that I was not able to establish a VPN Connection via Cisco VPN-Client from my Notebook also, which is connected to my Routers (Easy Box 803 A) WiFi directly.

First google searches did not point me to a solution. If you have any idea what might be the problem please let me know.

Comment: I believe both the Sophos Red10 and the Cisco VPN appliances have detection bits in there that may terminate a connection if selected applications are detected.  Did you contact your network guys?

Comment: @TheCompWiz Not now. Never heard about these Detection Bits. Can you provide more information so I can give those guys a hint?!